# Why is there weird number in transform, -90 to -89.9801

Tags: floating-point, game-engine, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Do you notice that sometimes, the number in transform is weird. Like:

- -90 to  -89.9801
- 270 be 271.00001
- or like this

Even that what you set originally is 90 or 270.

Why does this happen? Does it have some connections of unity's mechanisim?
[image]

Comment: where did u place the object in hirarchy or direct in scene?

Comment: I feel that this usually happen, when I duplicate object.

Comment: And this happend, not only in rotation. Sometimes, in scale or in position

Comment: if u duplicate then it will take same transform property

Comment: I feel that if u place an object directly to the scene then its change its transform while if u directly put in your hierarchy it will remain same

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan maybe u r right

Comment: yes I have experience it

Comment: It also maybe caused by the static objects baking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value displayed is a conversion from the quaternion value.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

Float always brings a bit of inaccuracy.

[Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

But mostly the first part. What is displayed is just for you to understand but this is not what Unity uses. You will also notice some jumps from 180 to -90 or 360 to -180 when you are rotating all axis. This is again due to the fact that a quaternion is just a direction regardless the 3 axis (quaternion actually has 4 dimensions) but based on angles and trigonometry.

Comment: this happened, not only in rotation. but also position

Comment: Then it is just the float rounding and inaccuracy. Sometimes you will see the scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that Unity does calculate its transformations with quaternions. The Euler Angles have to be calculated into a quaternion and so there's a little inaccurateness.

Comment: please see the comments, this not only happend in rotation